# NameError: uninitialized constant MyJob ActiveJob and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a problem with `sidekiq/activejob` integration. I have a controller that calls a `perform_later` method from a MyJob class. This works with the `perform` method, but when I change to `perfom_later`, the job is scheduled in my development log. However, when I see the sidekiq dashboard, at the retries section, I can see `NameError: uninitialized constant` (look below image)

[image]

These are my files:

```
# app/jobs/crime_job.rb
class CrimeJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(crime)
    puts "Perform #{crime}"
  end

  def self.job_name(crime)
    "RadarCrime:#{crime.id}"
  end 
end
```

Crime Controller

```
# app/controllers/crime_controller.rb
def show
  # [...]
  CrimeJob.perform_later(@crime)
end
```

Sidekiq initializer

```
# config/initializers/active_job.rb
Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Comment: Could you show us the full trace please? Also, it looks like you haven't defined the `perform_later` method in class `CrimeJob`

Comment: just to make sure, you are using rails4.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I also open an issue in Sidekiq repository, and the solution is easier than I've think.

Just restart the sidekiq process and it's works fine.

Issue link: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2207

Comment: Sounds elementary. Still wondering why I didn't do this 2 hours ago :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74023920/why-i-am-getting-this-error-warn-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-hijob i believe this is similar problem